# Deshabilitar Boton LLamando al Controlador en FXML Usando JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Cordial saludo, mi problema es el siguiente, quiero deshabilitar un Botón cuando el usuario se loguea, todo va bien en el Login pero cuando el usuario se loguea el boton no se deshabilita, he intentado llamando al controlador en el FXML y Pasando el boton que necesito deshabilitar pero aun no logro concretar esa parte. y si llamo al controlador como lo muestro no se carga la siguiente escena. Quisiera que me dieran una ayuda por aca:

Este el codigo del MainController en donde se hace el login y llama a otro Stage si el usuario y pass son validos:

```
public void  conexion () {
        String  usus="";
        String Passu ="";
        String Bd="jdbc:sqlserver://THUMANO2:1433;databaseName=QUORA";
        String Usuario="sa";
        String Pass="milkas87";
        String SqlQuery= "select NOMBREUSUARIO, CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), (DecryptByPassPhrase('*xc/6789oÑ---+y',PASS))) as PASS from usuarios where  CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), (DecryptByPassPhrase('*xc/6789oÑ---+y',PASS)))='"+fcontrasena.getText().toString().trim()+"'";
        Connection Conexion = null;

        try {
            Conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(Bd, Usuario, Pass);
            PreparedStatement ps =Conexion.prepareStatement(SqlQuery);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

             while(rs.next()) {
                 usus = rs.getString("NOMBREUSUARIO");
                 Passu = rs.getString("PASS");

             }

             if(fcontrasena.getText().toString().trim().equals(Passu) && fusuario.getText().toString().equals(usus)) {


                 try {

                        FXMLLoader carga = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Admin.fxml"));
                        Parent StackPane = carga.load();

                     **AdminScreenController controller= carga.getController();
                      controller.setBtn1(btn1);**


                        Stage administrador=new Stage();
                        Scene scene = new Scene(StackPane);
                        administrador.setScene(scene);
                        administrador.setTitle("AdminScreen");
                        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                        administrador.show();
                        Stage login=(Stage)fusuario.getScene().getWindow();
                        login.hide();


                 }catch(Exception e) {

                 }
                }


        }catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error","ERROR",0);
        }
    }
```

y en el AdminScreenController tengo esto:

```
public void setBtn1(Button btn1) {

         btn1.setDisable(false);
    }
```

Comment: Para deshabilitar es **btn1.setDisable(true);** o bien si quieres también puedes hacerlo invisible **btn1.setVisible(false);**

Answer (score 0):

En el FXMl, deshabilita el botón, y en el controlador lo habilitas de nuevo con btn.setDisable(true);

Answer (score 0):

LLame al controlador de esta manera con una variable que capturo de la Base de datos que valida si es usuario o administrador y dependiendo de eso se deshabilita el boton, igualmente llame al controlador y listo.

```
                        String h=LoginController.this.roladmin;
                        LoginController.this.setRoladmin(h);
                        String r=LoginController.this.getRoladmin();
                        AdminScreenController.setCapdata(r);



                          if(!r.equals("ADMINISTRADOR")) {

                                loadl.btnimg5.setDisable(true);
                                loadl.btnimg5.setStyle("-fx-opacity:0.65;");
                                loadl.useritem.setDisable(true);

                            }
                        else {
                            loadl.btnimg5.setDisable(false);
                            loadl.useritem.setDisable(false);
                        }
```